# apex:actionSupport 'action' was not fired, when using onchange attribute in apex:selectList

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, selectlist, actionsupport

Actionsupport action method is not fired when I use onchagen attribute in apex:selectlist. If I remove the onchange attribute from the selectlist then actionsupport is working as expected.

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedRectype}" size="1" onchange="reloadPage(this);">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!RecType}"/>
     <apex:actionSupport action="{!loadElements}" event="onchange" status="oppRecType"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Why this behaviour is happening..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use both `onchange` an an `actionSupport` for `onchange` at the same time. This is true for all events; you can use either the attribute or actionSupport, but not both on the same element.

Depending on your specific case, it seems appropriate that you'd probably want to call reloadPage after the actionSupport finishes:

```
<apex:actionSupport action="{!loadElements}" 
                    event="onchange" 
                    status="oppRecType" 
                    oncomplete="reloadPage(this)"/>
```

However, this may not behave correctly for `this`, so you'll want to try it out.

The alternative is to use an apex:actionFunction from your reloadPage script:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="loadTheElements" 
    action="{!loadElements}" reRender="someTarget" 
    status="oppRecType" />

function reloadPage(el) {
  loadTheElements();
  // Rest of code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `actionSupport` with `event="onchange"` thats which is wrapped inside `apex:selectList` thats why do not use `onchange` of `apex:selectList`.

Rather use other event to reload the page.

Would say, that better to `rerender` attribute of the `actionSupport` for page or section of the page rendering.

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedRectype}" size="1">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!RecType}"/>
     <apex:actionSupport action="{!loadElements}" event="onchange" status="oppRecType" reRender="form1"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Comment: I've to call javascript function as well as apex method